# Practice drills for finger drumming

Tags: practice, drums, midi-controller-drums, music-production-station

I have spent a bit of time learning to play drumkit but now I want to learn kit drumming with an MPC or midi controller in live performance.

Are there different drills I should practice to learn drumkit grooves and rudiments on a 4x4 touchpad?

On a kit, I only have 4 limbs to work with but with a touchpad I potentially have 8 "limbs" in two groups to use and coordinate. Would it be possible to learn to emulate two drumkits, like the Grateful Dead or the JB's?

Comment: With or without a kick drum pedal? I don't have one so I 'remember' what the kick should be doing & add it on a second take. Other than that I just use one finger on each hand & play it 'like a kit', all in one take. No fake three-handed drummer artefacts that way.

Comment: @tetsujin without.

Comment: Then, as I said above. Play as though you have two sticks, remember the kick part & overdub later. if you're not trying to emulate a real drummer, then the world's your oyster.

Comment: @tesujin I'm trying to emulate a real drummer.

Comment: Then as I already said - two fingers & remember the kick part for an overdub.